# Oracle Insert Performance Oscillates

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I have a relatively high volume Oracle 11g database into which I am inserting hundreds of thousands of records daily using Java and JDBC.  Until recently, Oracle has not had a problem keeping up with the volume.  Recently however, performance has begun to swing back and forth between acceptable and terrible.

For a several minutes, the ingestion will occur at about 500 transactions per second, then suddenly slow to 2 transactions per second.  After several minutes, the rate will again speed up to 500 transactions for a few minutes, and then back again.

Searching online has prompted me to work with the redo logs ... I now have six redo logfile groups, each with a pair of 500 Mb files on different disks.  This does not appear to have fixed the problem.  Interestingly, it seems I can sometime trigger the database to temporarily improve from the 2 trans/sec to the 500 trans/sec by issuing the Oracle command "alter system switch logfile".

I have also toyed with the ARCHIVELOGMODE and "select /*+ append */ ..." approach to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps not directly relates to the issue you are having, presume that you are using batch updates.

Comment: Do you insert records using insert statements Java using JDBC or do you use a Stored Procedure to insert records?

Comment: I'm doing many long series of JDBC "insert" statements with "commits" after every 1000 or so inserts.  No stored procedures.

Comment: I suggest you provide the code snippet of your JDBC part so that others can have a look to analyze if necessary. Besides, for such operations use a  stored procedure to do the insert using BULK COLLECT or FOR ALL for better handling of insert statements. Once the stored procedure is fully functional, you can call the stored procedure using JDBC.

Comment: Did you run a AWR report?

Comment: @R.Kirk Have a look at [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f%3Fp%3D100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1210436024540), quite contrary to what I have mentioned. Perhaps it would be useful for you.

Comment: @R.Kirk maybe you are not making 500 tran/sec but 500 batch inserts/s and while it slows down, actual transactions are commited.

Comment: I am toying with your suggestions user75ponic, but I have a very low confidence level.  OldProgrammer, I am unable to use OEM because of its failure to configure properly (ORA-12641).  I am 99.9% convinced the error is not in the Java or JDBC code - running the exact same ingestion code against a different database works perfectly (500 inserts/second).  It must be a configuration issue.  Keep in mind, performance oscillates, it is not always bad.